# how to delete user input command after reply

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Python Bot not deleting user input command after sending reply. i added `await bot.delete_message(message)` in last line still its not deleting after replying.

example: after bot reply's `Pong`. it should delete `?ping`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await bot.delete_message(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no variable name `message`. Instead delete the message provided with the invocation context

```
await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
```